Failed Marriage questions
"I find myself torn between the idea of reconciling with my ex-wife, whom I divorced six years ago, and pursuing a relationship with another woman whom I deeply love. Despite having two children with my ex-wife, I no longer feel a romantic connection with her. However, the thought of entering into another relationship after my previous attempts have failed leaves me feeling conflicted. At times, I contemplate reuniting with my ex-wife, but I am reminded that my feelings for her have faded. I can't help but wonder if this dilemma is a sign that I may spend the rest of my life alone, which leaves me feeling like I've failed in some way. I can tell even I forced myself on her to get the second child. Even now I am sure if I can make her happy because in my heart I don't love her
